# Blender scripting: Object intersection does not work after using spin()

Tags: mesh, scripting, intersection

I'm new to Python scripting in Blender, and trying to intersect two objects.
One of those objects is complex (spun/extruded multiple times), and when I try to call the intersection routine (intersect_mesh() at the last line of code), the intersection is empty (nothing appears on the screen).

I suspect it has to do with using mesh commands in edit mode (mode_set(mode='EDIT').

Any help would be appreciated,
-Alex

````
import bpy
import math, mathutils
import os, sys

QUALITY = 8
SPHERE_DIVS = int(QUALITY/2)+2
CYL_DIVS = 100 * QUALITY
MAJOR_S = int(256 * QUALITY/10)
MINOR_S = int(16 * QUALITY/10)

def intersect_mesh(a,b):
    mod = a.modifiers.new(b.name+"_isect", type='BOOLEAN')
    mod.operation = 'INTERSECT'
    mod.object = b
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = a
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier=mod.name)
    bpy.data.objects.remove(b, do_unlink=True)

R = 25.4 /4
STRING = 25.4 * 3/32
LEN = 25.4 /2 + 25.4 /4

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add(
    location =(-STRING,0,0),
    vertices = CYL_DIVS,
    radius = STRING,
    rotation = (-math.pi/8,0,0),
    depth = LEN)
bar = bpy.context.object

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
STEPS=8
for z in range(1,1+STEPS):
    frac = 1/STEPS
    vec = mathutils.Vector((2*STRING*frac,0.0,0.0))
    bpy.ops.mesh.extrude_region_move(
        TRANSFORM_OT_translate={"value":vec}
    )
    bpy.ops.mesh.spin(steps=1, angle=math.radians(-45)/STEPS, center=(0,0,0), axis=(1,0,0))
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')    

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(
    location=(0,0,10),
    size=20)
box = bpy.context.object
#intersect_mesh(bar,box)

```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's definitely slower, but I got it to work after adding `mod.use_self = True` into your `intersect_mesh` function.

From https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/booleans.html , It says that enabling self intersection is needed if one or both of the operands have self intersections. When you spin your cylinder around, you're creating self intersections within the cylinder object.

I also got it to work somewhat using `mod.solver = 'FAST`, but it left behind a messy edge sticking outwards.

Comment: That's very helpful, thank you kindly.. I think it will speed things up to make separate objects and then combine them instead of creating self-intersections by toying directly with the vertices in edit mode.